# unable to tick all the check box under a single page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing problem to apply loop and tick all the check box under a page.

Kindly suggest me to tick all the check box in page. 
Please follow the below steps
1. Go to Url "http://kesdee.com/buyOnline.html"
2. Go to dropdown'Course Groups' and select "Bank Branch Management"
3. tick all the check box under 'View Less' link
4. click all the 'View More' links one by one and tick all the check box

Working on selenium Web Driver using java.

I have tried it by using xpath, id's and classname, but unsuccessful.

Comment: How about you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: I applied the loop using xpath but unable to tick more than 5 check box.

Comment: I am unable to add my code here.

Comment: are the IDs consistent for the checkboxes?  chk_3223, chk_3224?

Comment: I was able to get a list of checkboxes using $("input[id*='chk_']") - what did you use?

Comment: No mike, id's vary for each check box

Comment: Mike, Can you give me mail id so that I can send you the code which I have wrote.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use selenium.support library.

https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html

after you can easy do selection of any option from this select. By id, value or index